# What is the difference between these two ways of defining a function inside an object?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know the difference between the following two ways of defining a function inside an object and the pros and cons of each way ?

```
let myObject = {
    fnWithinObject() {
        console.log("Function Within Object");
    },
    fnAttributeWithinObject: function() {
        console.log("Fn Attribute Within Object");
    }
}
myObject.fnWithinObject();
myObject.fnAttributeWithinObject();
```

Comment: I *think* that the ability to use `new` (or not) is the only difference, see linked question. I'd prefer the method syntax, it's more concise (but slightly less supported, because it's ES6 syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Not much, they are essentially functionally equivalent in an Object literal scenario. The shorthand version, on the other hand, is required when declaring it as a member of a class.